# How To Encrypt Zip Files using linux terminal?

Tags: kali-linux, encryption, zip

**Need A Help !**

I need how to encrypt zip file using *Kali Linux terminal* ! I tried hard! But i cannot learn it using my own knowledge!

Comment: you're using `zip`? Did you try typing `zip` just by itself - it gives help text. Or `man zip` and search for the word `encrypt` where it explains how to encrypt

Comment: If you're struggling at this, Kali is not the right distribution for you.

Answer (score 5):

1. `man zip`
2. Press <kbd>/</kbd>, type `pass`
3. You'll find:

```
 -e --encrypt
     Encrypt the contents of the zip archive using a password which is entered
     on the terminal in response to a prompt (this will not be echoed; if standard
     error is not a tty, zip will exit with an error). The password prompt is
     repeated to save the user from typing errors.
```

The command to compress files will be

`zip -e file.zip file1 file2 file3`

If you want to compress a directory and all directories and files within,

`zip -er file.zip directory`

Note: `zip` uses a relatively weak encryption scheme. If you're looking for something serious and industry recognized, use `7za` (from `p7zip`).

---

If you don't want to use console, install `wine` and WinRAR/7-zip under it. This way you won't have to deal with console.

Comment: thanx a lot friend! i will follow You!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with `gpg`.

1. `gpg -c filename.zip`
2. Enter passphrase to encrypt with
3. You should now have a file `filename.zip.gpg`
4. Move or delete the original file
5. Decrypt your new file with `gpg filename.zip.gpg` + entering your passphrase
6. It should now create a non-`.gpg` version of the file for you to access normally

Comment: You have omitted how to set up GPG which is an art in itself. And then such files won't be really portable as opening them would be a torture for other average people.

Comment: I don't even have a GPG key. I'm not so sure it requires as much setup as you're imagining.